# Xcode doesn't update UI in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I am developing one application, in that I am designing UI in `storyboard`. Like put `UILabel`, `UItableView`, `UICollectionView` and `Cell` for both, also inner subviews in cell.

I am setting `constraint` or any other properties, like color, font, spacing, default values, etc. Those changes are not updated in storyboard at  a time. Feels like Xcode is hanged. If I close `Xcode` and open again then only I can see changes.

Any meeting I need to do ? Anyone have solution, then please share.

Note : `Xcode 9.4` and `Xcode 9.3`

Here is screenshot : [image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide screenshots of your storyboards including the elements hierarchy

Comment: are you using any third party library?

Comment: @OhadM I have added screenshot.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz No, I have not used any third party classes or libraries.

Comment: Are you using any custom IBDesignable class?

Comment: @Lefteris Yes, I have created `IBDesignable` class for `UITextField`

Comment: There you have it @VRAwesome, that's your problem :)
IB tends to crash/not-compile when using IBDesignable/Inspectable

Comment: Is `StoryBoard - Editor - Automatic Refresh Views` enabled?

Comment: @OhadM But...then it should be for that respective control. Like I have created class for `UITextField`, then textfield only should have problem - not refreshed. What happen to other views ?

Comment: @Kerberos Yes... `StoryBoard - Editor - Automatic Refresh Views` is enabled. Let me add that image in my post.

Comment: Most likely the IBDesignable is failing and this is causing the problem

Comment: Look in console. Usually IBDesignable crashes are mentioned.

Comment: `then it should be for that respective control`. NOO. when IB crashes, whole storyboard does not render